# Convert Collection to Array with I=ID in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner php developer.
I have small problem with my array. I use in my project Laravel 7
I have this code:

```
$items = collect($discount->products->toArray());
```

It's result me:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1783 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:17 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "product_category_id" => 5
      "image_id" => null
      "vat_type_id" => 1
      "name" => "Produkt 1"
      "slug" => "produkt-1"
      "lead" => "<p>fewferfer</p>"
      "description" => "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
      "price" => "123.00"
      "loyalty_program_points_price" => 2
      "min_student_level" => null
      "marked_as_available_at" => "2020-09-30T11:45:51.000000Z"
      "deactivated_at" => null
      "created_at" => "2020-09-30T11:45:23.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2020-09-30T11:45:51.000000Z"
      "deleted_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:3 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:17 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "product_category_id" => 5
      "image_id" => null
      "vat_type_id" => 1
      "name" => "Produkt 2"
      "slug" => "produkt-2"
      "lead" => "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
      "description" => "<p>fergfer</p>"
      "price" => "21.00"
      "loyalty_program_points_price" => 3
      "min_student_level" => null
      "marked_as_available_at" => "2020-09-30T11:45:38.000000Z"
      "deactivated_at" => null
      "created_at" => "2020-09-30T11:45:38.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2020-09-30T11:45:38.000000Z"
      "deleted_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:3 [▶]
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need convert it to this result:

```
Array{
    1 => 1 (id)
    2 => (id)
}
```

How can I make it?
I need array with only id values

Comment: Use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck). `$items = collect($discount->products->toArray())->pluck('id')->toArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections have the [pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-pluck), which allows you to grab all the values of a specific key. To get all of the ids, you'd just need to do

```
$ids = $items->pluck('id')->all();
```

If you want them to have the same key as the id as well, pass that as the second parameter

```
$ids = $items->pluck('id', 'id')->all();
```

As a note, if products is a relation, then it's already a collection. You do not need to convert it to an array, then back to a collection:

```
$product_ids = $discount->products->pluck('id')->all();
```